# How to extract the dynamic text inside <nobr> using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fetch the server file name which is in text format in DOM inside a `<nobr>` tag and I am getting an invoker error.

**Error**

```
Invokemethod error(source not found)
Need the text to be stored in string using selenium webdriver- "/services/aps/load_files/upload/WireTransfer_BatchImport_CForeignUSD_155342006955_201901250134.csv"
```

**HTML Code**

```
<table id="innerTable" class="summaryTable" cellspacing="0" 
  cellpadding="0" style="">
  <tbody>
    <tr
       onclick="updateOID('155341609897','E_IMPORT_FILE_UPLOADED');
       onRowClick();" 
       rowvalues="155341609897E_IMPORT_FILE_UPLOADED" 
       class="summaryRow_Even">
      <td class="summaryCell" nowrap="" style="width: 275px;">
        <nobr 
           style="width:275px;">
             WireTransfer_BatchImport_CForeignUSD.csv&nbsp; 
        </nobr>
      </td>
      <td class="summaryCell" nowrap="" style="width: 631px;">
         <nobr 
            style="width:631px;">
            /services/aps/load_files/upload/WireTransfer_BatchIm 
            port_CForeignUSD_155342006955_201901250134.csv&nbsp; 
         </nobr>
      </td>
```

What I had tryied so far

```
String text = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='innerTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/nobr/text()")).getText();
String text = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='innerTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/nobr/text()")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Also tried,

```
String text = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//nobr[contains(text(),'/services/aps/load_files/upload/WireTransfer_BatchImport_CForeignUSD')]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work //nobr[contains(text(),'/aps')]

[image]